# How to solve this IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x' =-5x-y$
$y' =4x-y$

I got
$x=ae^{-3t}+bte^{-3t}$
$y=-2bte^{-3t}+2ae^{-3t}+be^{-3t}$

$a=0$ $b=0$

The answer is
$x=e^{-3t+3}-te^{-3+3}$ 
$y=-e^{-3+t}+2te^{-3+3}$

I dont understand where the +3 comes from

Comment: Which are the initial values?

Answer (score 1):

They are several typing mistakes in the wording of the question.

Your result for $x(t)$ is correct. Check your $y(t)$ to correct false sign of coefficients.

$a=0$ and $b=0$ are absurd. They must be computed from the missing initial values. Probably $a=e^3$ and $b=-e^3$. The $+3$ in the exponent of $e^{-3t+3}$ comes from these values of $a$ and $b$.